# read-ing an octal number

Tags: haskell, ghci

Octal numbers are part of Haskell's integer syntax. Also `lex` recognizes it:

```
Prelude> lex "0o10"
[("0o10","")]
```

But `read` does not (ghc 8.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04):

```
Prelude> read "0o10"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

The report is not very clear on this in 6.3.3. It just states that `lex` reads a lexeme and that `lex` is used by `read`. Is this intended?

Comment: That's the same error you would get with *any* argument to `read`, because you haven't specified what type of value you want back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `read "0o10"` is:

```
GHCi> :t read "0o10"
read "0o10" :: Read a => a
```

In GHCi, the type variable `a` will be defaulted to `()`, [as explained in the User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.2/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci):

```
GHCi> read "()"
()
```

Note that the behaviour you describe is not limited to strings that would be parsed as octals...

```
GHCi> read "[1,2,3]"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

... and that [`lex :: ReadS String`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:lex), unlike `read`, specifically produces `String` results, rather than allowing you to pick an instance of `Read`.

To get the behaviour you expect, provide a suitable type annotation or signature:

```
GHCi> read "0o10" :: Integer
8
```